# Distinguish scrolling by scrollbar / mousewheel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, web

is there any way to distinguish whether the page is scrolling based on mousewheel or by dragging the scrollbar? I need to do different action for both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there are some existing plugins to deal with mousewheel events:

https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel

These take the existing `onmousewheel` events and make them cross-browser, although I think recent versions of jQuery might already do this with the `mousewheel` event:

`$('#myselector').bind('mousewheel', function() { } );`

Answer (score 0):

Use `mousewheel` event which will be triggered on when mouse wheel is used to scroll the page from [here](http://brandonaaron.net/code/mousewheel/demos).